# Why is pandas turning into numpy at recursion with large numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recursion

Why is this working with size 1000 but not with a larger size like 10.000?
It seems like the pandas series is transformed into a numpy array with larger numbers?

```
def recursive(x):
    if len(x) == 1: 
        return pd.Series(0)    
    return pd.Series(x.iloc[0]).append(recursive(x.iloc[1:]))

recursive(pd.Series(np.zeros(1000))) #all good
recursive(pd.Series(np.zeros(10000))) #AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Comment: I have narrowed it down to `2939`, where it is still working and `2940`, where it fails. I believe it has something to do with pandas memory saving.

Answer (score 1):

You're running out of memory and not able to generate another pandas series.

Pandas is very flexible -- perhaps there's a non-recursive way to solve your problem?